# (External USB) HDD not accessible as usual after strange behaviour

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, ntfs

first of all, I'm using Linux (but have access to a Windows PC as well).
During some data transfer, my external USB hard disk drive (NTFS formatted) suddenly was no more accessible, I could not unmount it and `fuser -mv /dev/sdc1` told me it was used just by the `mount.ntfs` process. I had no idea, so I just killed this process. Then it was not mounted anymore, of course.
But I could not use this USB port anymore. I'm using a USB switch for multiple devices. Then, after a few minutes of investigation, my mouse turned off, I could not use it anymore as well - to be more precisely, the port of the mouse, which is next to the first mentioned port. I still could use other ports and the hdd was working fine. But after a few minutes, the same thing happend, made the 'new' USB port unusable as well.

I could not find the hdd with `lsblk` while in the unusable ports, but `lsusb` still showed me my disk. So I decided to reboot. Everything fine again - at first. But at some point, the same thing happened.

Now, after reboot, on a working USB port, my hdd is mountable again. I'm trying to figure out
-what happened
-how to fix this (it still occurs after some time of data transfer)

`lsblk` shows my hdd now.
I tried the `chkdsk` utility from Windows. This found some errors, corrected them, but still, the problem persists.
Then I ran a full `chkdsk` (see 3rd Update) without finding any errors.
I tried the `ntfsfix /dev/sdc` - didn't find anything.
I tried to use `smartctl`, but `smartctl --scan` does not find my disk.
Forcing it by `smartctl -ax /dev/sdc` gives the error `Unknown USB bridge [0x1058:0x1230 (0x1050)]`.
Specifying it with `smartctl -axd sat /dev/sdc` does work, I performed the short, the convenience and the extended test - without any errors. Just the attributes data (`TYPE`) made me a bit curious:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   214   175   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6275
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2456
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
```

The rest is just `Old_age`...

Any ideas, what could help me? Is my hardware damaged (if so, I have no idea why, it's relatively new, nothing special until now)? What should I do? Since this is my biggest drive, I can't do a complete backup at the moment.

**Update**: I will (have to?) try to use `badblocks` and/or `e2fsck`. I wanted to avoid this, because it takes terribly long, but I have no better idea... I will update, when (if) something finishes. I will start it tomorrow...

**Update**: Added correct `smartctl` command with its results so far. I will run an extended test soon, but it takes more than 8 hours.

**Update**: I ran the `chkdsk /f /r` from Windows. This includes searching for bad sectors and trying to correct them. It took more than 48 hours to finish... Result: No errors. Next, I'm going to do the extended SMART test...

**Update**: The extended SMART test found no errors either. It took more than nine hours to complete... What to do next?

Comment: No idea what the actual problem is, but it sounds like it has something to do with your USB switch. Anyway, for the `smartctl` part, you want to use `-d sat` for a SATA drive behind a USB adapter (the enclosure). Your adapter may not necessarily support ATA passthrough though, so no worries when it doesn't work. As a last resort, you can also try `-d scsi`, it won't give you much info though (also may not really reflect the actual health of your SATA drive).

Comment: Ah, you are right, my bad - of course. `smartctl -d sat` does what it should, I will update my post soon. Thx! I don't think it's the switch because I tried a port of my mainboard as well... And everything else works well.

Comment: Did you build the drive yourself (I mean like, getting an internal 2.5" SATA HDD and a USB enclosure) or was it from some vendor (e.g. WD MyPassport)?

Comment: No, it is a WD MyBook, nothing self built. The (long) Windows checkdisk with searching for bad sectors and correcting them finished now (after more than 48h). No errors. Next I'm going to do an extended Smart Test I guess...

Comment: After the SMART extended test finished without any errors, I'm wondering, what's wrong with my disk...

Comment: It might not be the disk that is dying, but the USB bridge (or maybe neither is dying but just bad contact). I have an USB/SATA adapter in hand that doesn't really support "SATA hot plug", if I disconnect the disk from it (instead of disconnecting it from the USB port), it will start freezing my other USB devices too, and then the whole system and causes a full reset (though this might be because my Windows is installed on another USB drive). It makes me think of your case.

Comment: This sounds similar to my problem, you're right. I'm just wondering, why this has occured recently. I haven't moved the drive for multiple months. I think it's the best trace anyway because of missing alternatives.  However, I have just started some file transfer again. I will report how it's going.

Comment: Until now (>40GB data written) no problems so far. Thank you Tom Yan! Any idea what I should do with this question now - without answer?